# How to recover Root Directory folders in filezilla for PHP server

Tags: php, filezilla

Accidentally the root directory file 
-public_html
-etc
-public_ftp
-access_log file has deleted ...

so plzz help me how to recover those file

[image]

Comment: That can only be done on the maschine that holds the files with an file-recovery tool. Not via filezilla.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

No FTP client I'm aware of will download an entire directory tree to a local backup directory when you issue a *delete* command. That would make deletions slow as hell and will exhaust your hard disc sooner or later. You'll have to restore from backup and/or upload again your local copy. If you don't have any of those, you're in trouble.

Server files are probably gone, esp. if the server has not been shut down immediately. You might be able to get a partial recovery with the usual forensic tools but even if that path's possible (if it's a server hosted in third-party facilities it normally won't) you'd never be sure of what's missing.